# How to train a Word2vec model so that particular words set would reside close to each other in the vector space?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, word-embeddings

I am supposed to build a resume parser. For the skill extraction part,  currently I am matching bi-grams and uni-grams in a CV against a predefined skill set, which is not that successful. Can I train a Word2vec model so that words and phrases in a cv which could classify as skills to have similar word vectors?

Is there any method which could be more successful?
Please help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you try running word2vec already? What results did it return?

Comment: @Leevo no i did not, actually i don't know how to do it.

Comment: I suggest you to first try with word embeddings. You can do it with **gensim**, a Python library that allows you to train word2vec models from scratch. If it doesn't work, then you must think about something else. I can't think of a good reason why it wouldn't work. Similar skill words tend to appear in similar contexts, therefore a word2vec model should be able to learn that and represent these words close together.

Comment: @Leevo, thank you. I will try that.